# Show embedded component on click

Tags: angular

I have two components named "app-new-employees-header" and "app-help-popout". I would like to show the the "app-help-popout" when I click a button on the "app-new-employees-header". Currently I am not seeing the "app-help-popout" even without any button click functionality.

Here is my code

app-new-employees-header.html

```
<nav>
  <div class="row row-1 new-employees-header">
    <div >
      <button id="help-btn">
        <img id="help-icon-1" src="../../../../assets/icons/note_success_xlarge_white.png">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<app-help-popout ></app-help-popout>
```

app-help-popout.html

```
<button id="open-btn" *ngIf="!isOpen" (click)="isOpen = true"><img src="../../../assets/icons/notes_small_white.png"></button>
<div *ngIf="isOpen" id="feedback-window">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <button id="close-btn" (click)="isOpen = false"><img src="../../../assets/icons/close(old).png"></button>
    <h3>Help</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="existingFeedback">
        <label>Your previous feedback</label>
      </div>
      <div id="notes-container">
        <label>My notes</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Add notes here"></textarea>
        <button class="main" (click)="close()"> close </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app-help-popout.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-help-popout',
  templateUrl: './help-popout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./help-popout.component.scss']
})
export class HelpPopoutComponent implements OnInit {

  isOpen: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

}
```

I am not sure why the popout is not showing, any ideas?

Comment: <div *ngIf="isOpen" id="feedback-window">   --> *ngIf="isOpen"----is your issue i think  since isOpen is false

Comment: do you see any error in console ? and remove all *ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a space typo in `<app-help-popout ></app-help-popout>` and that's why you can't even see the button from popout.

There's a better way on how you can handle that. With your approach you are always loading your popout component, even if you don't click on a button - it will be loaded.

What you can do is move the button responsible for opening the component to `app-new-employees-header`, and use [Output()](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs) to handle the closing

```
<button id="open-btn" (click)="showHelpPopout = true"><img src="../../../assets/icons/notes_small_white.png"></button>

<app-help-popout (closePopout)="closePopout()" *ngIf="showHelpPopout"></app-help-popout>
```

That way your popout component will load only after you click on a button. How ever if you need it to be loaded all the time (As this will recreate the component every time you close it and then open it again), you can apply your approach and just fix the typo.

The best approach would be to load the component on first button click and then leave it loaded to allow toggling (open / close) without recreating the component.